# What is the Entry Code in DllMain for a Hook Callback function

Tags: c++, c, winapi, dll, hook

What is the reason code in a DLL, when a thread specific hook is set?
Can anyone please help me out with this?

Thanks,
Ashish.

Comment: DLL entry is DllMain usually. Hooks are irrelevant

Comment: Ah! My bad sorry editing the question.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer: I wanted to know the reason code.

Comment: @Nawaz Does it still not make sense?

Comment: @AshishKumarShah: The grammar is weird. What do you mean when you ask : *"What is the reason code in a DLL, when a thread specific hook is set?"*.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still not clear, but I assume you mean using `SetWindowsHookEx()` to install a system wide hook, and so inject your dll into the address space of all apps.

The reason code will be `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`, since you are attaching to a process.

Comment: Will it still be DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH if i make the hook thread specific? DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH happens the moment i do a LoadLibrary from the caller process. I wanted to know the entry code when i set a hook to a thread in a another process

Comment: Yes. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx (_Note that a DLL's entry-point function is called with this value only by threads created after the DLL is loaded by the process. When a DLL is loaded using LoadLibrary, existing threads do not call the entry-point function of the newly loaded DLL._)

Comment: I am not setting a system wide hook.

Comment: Then you need to explain exactly what you are doing. Your question is too vague.

Comment: I am setting a WH_GETMSG hook to an internet explorer thread, i want to know the reason code when my callback function is called for the first time.